AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1 Node 1 disconnected. Apache Kafka y Spark
I'm running a Docker Compose setup with Spark and Kafka, but I'm encountering connectivity issues when Spark tries to connect to Kafka. My docker-compose.yml file includes services for both Kafka and Spark, and everything seems to be set up correctly. However, when running a Spark job that consumes data from Kafka, I get the following errors:
24/12/13 23:28:02 WARN NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

  spark:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - 'C:/docker-proyecto/spark-data:/opt/spark'
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no

  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
    depends_on:
      - spark
    volumes:
      - 'C:/docker-proyecto/spark-data:/opt/spark'

I'm running the following spark-submit command:
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.3 /opt/spark/script.py

In the script I'm trying to consume data from kafka
kafka_servers = "localhost:9092"
stream_df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", "topic1,topic2") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

24/12/13 23:28:02 WARN NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
The idea is that Spark can connect to Kafka without any problem, to read the data from the topics and manipulate them to save them in an HDFS, but it can't even connect and I don't know why. I've tried everything that my little experience in Docker has allowed me to.
